# How to put a C# GUI into a website? what do I need to do?

Tags: c#

The main program is written in C++ and packed into .dll file.
A C# written GUI takes that .dll file and run and display so that people can see what is going on.

I don't need to know anything about how that program works (it is a chess game). I just need to somehow put that GUI into a webpage so that people can view the GUI and play from a webpage.

For now what I have is a bunch of files that including the C++ codes and .dlls and the C# GUI with a .exe file.

I am new to web world...  please help me out.
I am not sure what to do...

-Franklin

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/%20Silverlight)

The other way would be implementing a gui with [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/%20ASP.NET)

Anyway I recommend you to learn about web technologies, before you decide which is best for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

gui is inside c++ is that what you mean ?
if that is so there is no way to express it to web as far as i know
unless you wrap your c++ dll build a ui in web and interface by wrapping the methods inside dll

Comment: the GUI is written in C#. the AI brain (strategy) is written in C++ and packed as .dll files

Comment: you should read through this hope you already managed to solve the problem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of ASP.NET MVC4 for building a responsive web application. On the server side, you can reference your dll and you can probably also use parts of your GUI code and change it to controller code to ouput the GUI to a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

For rapid development you may look on  [Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/), but I, personally, would suggest to spend little bit more time and do int `HTML5`.

- Silverlight is good for fast development of your C# UI on web, but client has to install plugin in order to be able to run it (like Adobe Flash), in consiquence, it is not supported on all platforms.
- HTML5 runs everywhere, instead. Int's just richer HTML with more built-in capabilities and features, supported by wide range of browser and system production companies. So, in my opinion, it's more reliable and scallable choice then Silverlight. But less productive, there is a learning curve.

In both cases you need to define interface that "asks" chess library for next move, by providing (I immagine), or currest state of the chess board, or the move made made by a gamer. By getting responce, render it on client side. So network trafic will be only "MOVE DONE" or "BOARD STATE" sent to a server and "NEXT MOVE" information got from the server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about how to put that C# UI into a webpage by using silverlight...

Comment: @KaichengFeng: it's not somethign that can be explained in a couple of comments unfortunately. If you are familiar with WPF, you will find your self very easy in Silverlight. If don't know WPF, you may think of looking on HTML5 too. I mean, it all depends if UI is already ready or not. If it's already ready (Windows Forms applicaton, say) you may think of moving it Silverlight, but first readng a couple of articles and samples on it.

Comment: do I have to re-write the UI in Silverlight? or just move it into Silverlight.

Comment: if it's written in Windows Forms: you have to rewrite it in Silverlight, if it's written already in WPF, there is much less work to do, but by the way, you ned to rewrite. Silverlight is a small subset of WPF, so not all functionalities available in WPF are available in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is in fact the closest solution to C# GUI on Web. As it is also built on .NET, some methods will already be familiar to you. I assume that your GUI is built in Windows Forms, so you will still have to rebuild the GUI for Web. Although in this question there is an answer with a converter described, which you could try: [can I convert windows forms based desktop app to silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818649/can-i-convert-windows-forms-based-desktop-app-to-silverlight)

However, I would recommend a complete rebuild of the GUI in either HTML or Silverlight. It just makes more sense for future development. **I would also suggest building a REST API for the C++ DLL wrapper, which you can call from almost any GUI, even the C# one that is already built.**